# Rotation vector sensor behaves like Game rotation vector sensor

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-sensors, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am facing a problem with Rotation Vector sensor on Android 5.1.1. 
My code:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
     float[] inputSensorMat = new float[16];
     float[] outputSensorMat = new float[16];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(inputSensorMat, event.values.clone());
    // since default orientation is landscape, we need to swap axis
    // (see documentation of remapCoordinateSystem)
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inputSensorMat,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
            outputSensorMat);
    Log.v(getClass(),     Constants.NEW_ORIENTATION(Arrays.toString(outputSensorMat)));
    mMatrix = new Matrix4x4(outputSensorMat, true);
}
```

The rotation matrix is then used in Rajawali to render the scene.
My problem is:
On Android 5.1.1 the rotation vector appears to give relative values, depending on the initial orientation / does not take geomag. sensor into account - i.e. when I start the app. heading east, it model is rendered by my right hand. When I start the app. heading north, model is rendered by my right hand too, instead behind me.
I tested it on NVidia Shield tablet (2 devices), oneplus one with cyanogen mode and Nexus 7.
The percieved behaviour fits the description of Game Rotation Vector sensor, but NVidia Shield does not have it implemented.

However, the same code behaves corretly on Android 4.1.2 and 4.4.

Any idea why is this happening or how to fix it?

Edit:
Might it be that I am using android:targetSdkVersion="19"? The same value is set in project build target in Eclipse (which I use instead of Android Studio). I cannot set higher API due to my dependency on OpenCV (see [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/54450/error-opencv4android-caused-by-javalangillegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit/))